# Calculate range of percentiles in Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssas

I'm using Sql Server 2014, I can get all the add-ons, SSAS, whatever's needed.

I have a table that for simplicity contains a single column with integers. It's safe to assume it contains 10^5 - 10^6 rows.

I want to calculate the 5th, 10th, 15th...90th, 95th percentile.

I can do it quite easily by calling percentile_cont (or _disc) 18 times. Unfortunatelly, it takes forever.

The thing is, I'm quite certain those calls do the same thing over and over again.

Is there a way to calculate a range of percentiles over a table faster?

I can easily do this in C#, by loading all rows into memory, ordering them, and just asking for 0.05*array.Length item, 0.1*array.Length item etc. - and it's obviously blazingly fast. I can of course replicate that by using a table variable or a temporary table, but I'm surprised there isn't some built in way.

Comment: Try running `percentile_cont()` as separate columns rather than as separate queries.

Comment: When working with percentiles, bear in mind that the term is ambiguous.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile.  Make sure that the calculation method meets your business requirements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yeah, of course - it was `select percentile_cont() as p05,percentile_cont() as p10,...`. Still very, very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `ntile()` and aggregation:

```
select nt, min(num), max(num), count(*)
from (select t.*, ntile(20) over (order by num) as nt
      from t
     ) t
group by nt
order by nt;
```

I should also add that SQL Server should make use of an index on the column for the window functions.  So, you might be able to speed up your approach just by adding an index.

Comment: `Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: Ok, now it works: `select nt, min(num), max(num), count(*) from
(
select num,  ntile(20)   over(order by table.num) as nt from table
) a
group by nt
order by nt;`

Comment: I just compared it to the 18-percentile_disc call, and it gives the same result (in the max column), while being immensly faster. Thank you!